# if X a subset of R which is order-isomorphic to R, is it a union of intervals?

Tags: real-analysis, order-theory

Recall that $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is **order-isomorphic** to $\mathbb{R}$ whenever there is an bijective map $j:X\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $j(x)<j(y)$ if and only if $x<y$.

**Conjecture 1.**  If $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and $X$ is order-isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, then $X$ is the union of disjoint intervals of $\mathbb{R}$ of positive measure.

This seems to strong to be true.  On the other hand, it *seems* like if it were false then it should be easy to produce a counter-example, which I have as yet been unable to do.

I might be able to get by with the following, weaker conjecture.

**Conjecture 2.**  If $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and $X$ is order-isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, then $X$ is the union of disjoint intervals of $\mathbb{R}$ of positive measure, as well as a set of measure zero.

Comment: I don't think conjecture 2 is any more likely to be true than conjecture 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $K\subset\mathbb{R}$ be a closed, nowhere dense set of positive measure,
and let $U=\mathbb{R}{\setminus}K$.

Write $U=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty U_n$ as a union of nonempty, pairwise disjoint open intervals.

Let $V=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty V_n$, where $V_n$ is the open subinterval of $U_n$ with the same center, but half the length.

Explicitly, if $U_n=(a_n,b_n)$, let $V_n=(c_n,d_n)$, where
\begin{align*}
c_n&=\frac{3a_n+b_n}{4}\\[4pt]
d_n&=\frac{a_n+3b_n}{4}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Now let $X=K\cup V$.

Clearly $X$ cannot be expressed as the union of a measure zero set and a union of intervals.

For each positive integer $n$, let $f_n:U_n\to V_n$ be defined by 
$$f_n(x)=\frac{2x+a_n+b_n}{4}$$
and let $f:\mathbb{R}\to X$ be defined by
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x&\text{if}\;x\in K\\[4pt]
f_n(x)&\text{if}\;x\in U_n\\[4pt]
\end{cases}
$$
Then it's easily seen that $f$ is an order isomorphism from $\mathbb{R}$ onto $X$.